# How to open the Device Manager with Python

Tags: python, subprocess

How do I open the Device Manager with python? I use the subprocess library:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("devmgmt.msc")
```

I get this error:

```
  File "c:\Wichtig\python\admpwd\admpwd.py", line 3, in <module>
    subprocess.call("devmgmt.msc")
  File "C:\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 304, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 756, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1155, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-access-device-manager-from-the-command-prompt-2626360):

In Windows 10, 8, 7, and Vista, Device Manager is included as an applet in Control Panel. This means that there's an associated Control Panel applet command available.

Use either of the following lines to launch the Device Manager

```
subprocess.call("control /name Microsoft.DeviceManager")

subprocess.call("control hdwwiz.cpl")
```

Comment: is there a way to control it? for example delete one of keyboard driver

Answer (score 2):

Use [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) to execute 'devmgmt.msc'...

```
import os
os.system('devmgmt.msc')
```